# Array manipulation to two series

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, jupyter

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 2.94642408, 25.7209404 ],
       [ 0.79932443,  6.12162428],
       [ 1.89396598, 14.46259769]])
```

I want to change it to two series like in which the first series has the elements on the left and the second series has the elements on the right. Ideally, in the end I want to add the resulting series to a dataframe.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use slicing and `pd.Series` constructor:

```py
s1 = pd.Series(a[:, 0])
s2 = pd.Series(a[:, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want series, go with j1-lee's answer.

Since you mentioned you eventually want a dataframe, you don't really need the in-between step of a series.

If you just take your array (lets call it `arr`) as follows

```
pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['series_1','series_2'])

   series_1   series_2
0  0.000000   0.000000
1  0.000000   0.000000
2  0.000000   0.000000
3  2.946424  25.720940
4  0.799324   6.121624
5  1.893966  14.462598
```

Comment: Both answers work. In my case, I want to add the series to an existing dataframe. So I just said the code from the other answer is equal to a column on that dataframe. Your answer works just as well though.